# Return a large struct object by value or pointer to dynamic allocation on C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

Here is my problem. I have a function that takes `struct` as input, allocates a new `struct` and then returns it. The `struct` has the following contents

```
struct Data {
std::vector<custom_type> vector_vars;
std::string key;
std::map<std::string, Data*> index;
};
```

`vector_vars` is of size 500-1000. custom_type if relevant is [this class](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/classz3_1_1ast.html). The `index` helps me access different `Data` struct by `key`. This is the function.

```
Data func(Data inputData) {

 Data outputData;
//compare values with inputData
//change some values in Data struct
 return outputData
}
```

1. Do I use stack allocation and return it so that it is copied to RHS. Is this advisable since copying may create a lot of overhead?
2. Can I return a reference/pointer to struct allocated on the stack within a function?
3. Is it advisable to use dynamic allocation instead here (may be with `std::shared_ptr`) for efficiency?

Comment: Do you need `outputData` to be different to `inputData`? If so, allocate on the stack and return by value.

Comment: 2 is certainly invalid. You can measure how 1 and 3 perform for your specific data and decide for yourself, my bet is on return by value (the compiler will optimize out the copying). You probably should pass the function argument by reference though.

Comment: `1` is usually correct; all modern compilers perform RVO, and in C++11 even if RVO isn't possible the return value will be moved.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Return the object by value. Copy elision is an optimization that the standard allows compilers to make that removes unnecessary copies. In C++03, the copy will almost certainly be elided by the compiler. In C++11, the copy will first be considered as a move (which will in turn move its contents) and even that may be elided.

   > in a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-unqualified type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the function’s return value

   Specifically, when this criteria results in copy elision, it is commonly known as named return value optimization, a form of [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

   So the most idiomatic and performance-friendly option here is to return by value. Of course, if you *measure* that even under optimization returning by value *is a problem*, then sure, you may consider dynamically allocating (see point 3).
2. No, you should not return a reference or pointer to a local variable. The object with automatic storage duration (what you refer to as allocating on the stack) will not exist any more. The reference or pointer will be left dangling. Using it in any meaningful way will result in undefined behaviour.
3. No, as mentioned above, it is advisable to return by value. However, if you really, really need to, you may dynamically allocate your `Data` and return it by smart pointer. The preferred smart pointer here would be a `std::unique_ptr` as your function is passing ownership to the calling function (not sharing ownership).

Comment: Thanks for the explaining in such detail. How should the `std::map` look? Should it be `std::map<std::string,Data>` or `std::map<std::string,Data*>`?

Comment: @user592748 It depends on whether the map should be referring to the same objects as everywhere else or if a copy is fine. That depends on the problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. Actually, one of two fast operations could happen here: either `outputData` could be moved into the return value, or this move could be elided. In neither case will there be any expensive copies. The copy of `inputData` seems unnecessary, perhaps you should pass it as `Data const& inputData`.
2. You could do this, but it would result in undefined behaviour.
3. No. Dynamic allocation is likely to be less safe, slower, more confusing and generally worse.

Comment: +1, but I think it is clearer to say that the copy could be elided *or* if not, it could still be moved. Elision trumps move.

Answer (score 2):

```
Data func1(Data inputData) {
    Data outputData;
    return outputData
}
```

takes the object of type `Data` by value and creates another instance of `Data` which is then returned by value. So the copy is created not only when the `outputData` is being returned, but also when `inputData` is being received. Don't worry about the performance while returning by value, there are mechanisms that will take care of it (worth to mention *copy elision* and possible *return value optimization*). I recommend you to pas `inputData` by reference though: `Data func1(const Data& inputData)`.

> *Is this advisable since copying may create a lot of overhead?*

Rule of thumb: Don't worry about the performance of your code unless you face performance issues.

> *Can I return a reference/pointer to struct allocated on the stack within a function?*

Don't return a reference / pointer to the object with automatic storage duration defined within the scope of that function. The object is destructed once the execution goes out of scope, so you will end up with *dangling pointer* (*invalid reference*) which will lead to **undefined behavior**

> *Is it advisable to use dynamic allocation instead here for efficiency?*

Avoid dynamic allocation wherever possible. Not because of efficiency, but for the sake of the memory management within your code. Follow [RAII idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and avoid handling the ugly memory management on your own.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing to the that rule of thumb and programming idiom

Comment: @user592748: You're welcome :) Premature optimization is never good.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite `func()` to take return a `Data*` instead of a `Data`.  Certainly it's much faster to copy a `Data*` than it is to copy a  `Data`.  But before that: do you care?  Does this function run once during program initialization, taking a tenth of second of wall clock time, or do you expect to call it once a frame, or what?

When you're writing a program, or optimizing an existing one, your goal should always be to make it "fast enough" (and "responsive enough", but never mind that for now).  The definition of "fast enough" varies a lot: in a simulation you might be happy to crunch one terabyte of data per hour, while in a video game you need to show the player a new graphics frame every 16 milliseconds.

So: is your program "fast enough" with just stack allocation?  If it is, leave it alone.  If it's not, use dynamic allocation instead.  In general, it's good C++ style to return pointers instead of large structs, but you shouldn't worry about that while you're still learning.  Make it work, make it right, *then* make it fast.